# What is "IB Symbol" in Interactive Brokers?

Tags: interactive-brokers

What is "IB Symbol" in Interactive Brokers? Why is it sometimes different from the "Symbol"?

For example, in [Xetra exchange](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/?f=%2Fen%2Ftrading%2Fetfs.php%3Fexch%3Dibis), the iShares Core MSCI EM IMI UCITS ETF has Symbol IS3N, as expected. But its IB Symbol in the same table is EMIM. Same for LMWE in the table below.

[image]

Comment: Did you ask IB?

Comment: I know, no answers in comments. Whatever https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/product/instant-bloomberg/

Comment: I did, the answer from Interactive Brokers support was: "I do not have a reason for why they may be different. IB symbol is what we have in our platform. It may be for coding purposes, but I cannot give a definitive answer." But, based on your link, "IB" stands not for "Interactive Brokers", rather "Instant Bloomberg"...